# Arduino serial port commnuication with Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, arduino

I am currently working on a project in which I need to read value from Arduino via serial port with pyserial and display them in a real-time plot using matplotlib. The problem is that it sometimes gives me errors, saying that

1. It cannot convert string to float;
2. The list (array) where I store data is out of range;

Arduino side is working perfectly, and the problems here come from python side.

#### Here is the error log:

data conversion error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py", line 216, in process
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 953, in _start
    self._init_draw()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1732, in _init_draw
    self._draw_frame(next(self.new_frame_seq()))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1755, in _draw_frame
    self._drawn_artists = self._func(framedata, *self._args)
  File "/media/ryuu/PFDirectory/Arduino/PythonArduino/pyRealTime.py", line 27, in plotting
    f0 = float(arduinoArray[0])
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

index out of range:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py", line 216, in process
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 953, in _start
    self._init_draw()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1732, in _init_draw
    self._draw_frame(next(self.new_frame_seq()))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1755, in _draw_frame
    self._drawn_artists = self._func(framedata, *self._args)
  File "/media/ryuu/PFDirectory/Arduino/PythonArduino/pyRealTime.py", line 28, in plotting
    f1 = float(arduinoArray[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What's curious about this error is that, when I tried to re-run the code again despite the error it gave, it worked just fine and I was able to plot the data in real-time. However, I am getting 5/10 times failing to read data due to the error mentionned, and I would like to know if there is something wrong with my code:

#### Arduino code:

```
int photoPin =A0;
int ledOn = 10;
int ledOff = 9;
float lightVal;
int dt = 250;
int dtLED = 150;
float ledState;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(photoPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(ledOn,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledOff,OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {
  lightVal = analogRead(photoPin);
  //flash ledOn when light is on (lightVal >= 670)
  //flash ledOff when light is off (lightVal <= 350)
  if(lightVal>=670.0){
    digitalWrite(ledOn, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ledOff, LOW);
    ledState = 1.0;
    }
  else if(lightVal<=350.0){
    digitalWrite(ledOn, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledOff, HIGH);
    ledState = 0.0;
    }


  Serial.print(lightVal);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.println(ledState);

  delay(dt);
}
```

#### Python Code:

```
import serial
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation


arduinoData = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600, timeout=1)
arduinoArray = []

pr = []  # photoresistor
ls = []  # led state


# plot config
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 2)


# define a function used in animation function
def plotting(i):

    # if no data coming in, then don't read data
    while arduinoData.inWaiting() == 0:
        pass
    arduinoString = arduinoData.readline().strip()
    arduinoArray = arduinoString.decode('ascii').split(',')
    f0 = float(arduinoArray[0])
    f1 = float(arduinoArray[1])

    # print(f0)
    # print(arduinoArray[0])
    pr.append(f0)
    ls.append(f1)

    # plotting
    ax1.cla()
    ax1.plot(pr)
    ax2.cla()
    ax2.plot(ls)


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, plotting, interval=250)
plt.show()
```

Thank you in advance for you help

Comment: Did you check if `arduinoData` has values every time?

Comment: Yes, the `while arduinoData.inWaiting()==0` ensure that every time python reads value from serial port, or it is just going to `pass`. @zer02

Comment: Can you run the code multiple times and print arduinoArray?

Comment: I did, the data went from `byte`, after the `.decode('ascii')`, to `string`. And I was able to plot those values but sometimes it gave me the errors mentioned in question. So I am supposing that there is something wrong with the communication between Arduino and python, but I am not sure though. @zer02

Answer (score 0):

Older question but hopefully this helps someone.

I was experiencing similar problems. What I understand so far is that simply Serial.print()ing ASCII to, and reading from, the serial port without much transmission structure is not a very fast or robust solution.

I came across [pySerialTransfer](https://github.com/PowerBroker2/pySerialTransfer), a really handy library which packetizes your data as bytes and decodes them on the other end. It has a [companion library for Arduino](https://github.com/PowerBroker2/SerialTransfer).

My Arduino code:

```
#include "HX711-multi.h"
#include "SerialTransfer.h"
# - Removed some defines and declarations to simplify - #
HX711MULTI scales[NUM_GROUPS] = {scales1, scales2};      // Add all scale instances to an array so we can iterate over them

// Program Variables
long raw[NUM_GROUPS * CHANNEL_COUNT];      // Array to hold raw samples collected from each sensor
uint16_t sendSize;

SerialTransfer myTransfer;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  myTransfer.begin(Serial);
}

void loop() {
  //Read sensor values into an array
  scales[0].readRaw(raw);
  scales[1].readRaw(raw + 4);
  // contents of raw looks like: {-180279, -160207, 57267, -238712, -198426, -232254, 14375, -176826}

  // Send the contents of raw to Python via serial
  sendSize = myTransfer.txObj(raw);
  myTransfer.sendData(sendSize);
  delay(2);
  // Loop around, read new values from sensors, and send new values.
}
```

My Python Code:

```
from pySerialTransfer import pySerialTransfer as txfer

def get_packet(st_obj, chunk_size=1, obj_type=list, obj_byte_size=32, list_format='i'):
    chunk = []
    while True:
        for _ in range(chunk_size):
            while not st_obj.available():   # Call link.available() repeatedly to parse bits until it returns True
                pass
            
            chunk.append(st_obj.rx_obj(obj_type=obj_type,  # Then call link.rx_obj() to extract the data from the buffer
                                obj_byte_size=obj_byte_size,
                                list_format=list_format))

        yield chunk
        chunk = []

link = txfer.SerialTransfer('COM7', baud=115200)
link.open()
time.sleep(2) # allow some time for the Arduino to completely reset

stream = get_packet(link, chunk_size=8)
# stream is now a generator object which yields 'chunk_size' number of packets with each iteration. 

print(stream.__next__())  # Prints a new chunk of packets each time you run this line

for i, x in enumerate(stream):    # Print 10 chunks of 8 packets each
    if i == 10:
        break
    print(x) 
    
link.close()
```

Hopefully this saves someone some time!